# Перегнать XML в определенный DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Есть XML и заготовленная DataTable под него.

Как загрузить XML в определенный DataTable?

В DataSet есть метод ReadXml, но нужной перегрузки я не нашел.

Неужели перегнать можно только ручками и в цикле?

Comment: Так у DataTable тоже есть ReadXML https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fs0z9zxd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable.ReadXml(fileName);
```

Более подробное описание и действующий демонстрационный пример [**тут**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fs0z9zxd(v=vs.110).aspx).